# Ef Core - Use Automapper to get data from keyless View

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, automapper

I need to know if its possible to use Automapper to map a DTO property from a database view. Or maybe it is possible in the DbContext model configuration. Lets imagine that I have a business purpose for having a view that contains other pertinent data, but for the purposes of brevity, I have made the classes simple

Pertinent Nugets

- EF Core v3.1.7
- AutoMapper v10.0.0

I have an Entity

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a keyless View

```
public class BarVW {
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

The view is built in the DB Initializer class

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    @"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_Bar AS 
        select
            f.Id as FooId,
            f.[Name] as FooName
        from
            Foo f
        -- where some logic that makes a Foo appear in view"
);
```

Then the view is assigned to a DbSet in the DbContext class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BarVW>(eb =>
    {
        eb.HasNoKey();
        eb.ToView("v_Bar");
    });

public DbSet<BarVW> BarVW { get; set; }
```

In my FooDto, I need an additional property to my entity class that will indicate that this Foo exists in my database view v_Bar

```
public class FooDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsBar { get; set; }
}
```

For the Automapper config I have the following, but there isn't an a way that i know of that i can map my dto `IsBar` property from the BarVW DbSet

```
CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
   .ForMember(dto => dto.IsBar, opt => ??? ); // don't know what to put here
```

Comment: Add `IsBar` to `Foo` and set it there. This is not a mapping concern.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu `IsBar` is not a database property (column). `IsBar` is a business logic property where the result is determined by the FooId existing in the View

Comment: It's a database concern. It belongs in your own code, not in the AM configuration.

Comment: Could you use `BeforeMap` or `AfterMap` for this? What determines whether or not `IsBar` is true? Is it true if the entity is not null?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu No it isn't a database concern. Views cannot have navigable properties, so I cannot reference the View in the `Foo` class. So my question is still, how do I map the result of a View, to a property on a Dto?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu As I indicated in my question, I don't know if its an AM config issue, or DbContext Issue

Comment: @ColinM I've never used either of those methods, so i'm unfamiliar with their capabilities. `IsBar` is true, when the `Foo.Id` exists in the `BarVW.FooId`

As noted in the SQL script for the view, there is `where` logic to determine if the Foo record is in the View

Comment: @A.Dixon If `BarVW` only returns valid bars, then `FooDto.IsBar` will be `true` for all records returned from the view.

Comment: @lauxjpn only when Foo.Id == BarVW.FooId

Comment: Got it, so you query both, `Foo` and `BarVW`, but you want `FooDto.IsBar` only to be set to `true`, if the underlying `Foo` has been returned by the `BarVW` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish what you want is to introduce a navigation property (e.g. `Bars`) and use that in the mapping configuration (e.g. `opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bars.Any())`).

Here is a fully working sample console program, that demonstrates this approach:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public BarVW Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class BarVW
    {
        public int FooId { get; set; }
        public string FooName { get; set; }
        
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BarVW> BarVW { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63850736")
                .UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(b => b
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                .HasData(
                    new Foo {Id = 1, Name = "Fo"},
                    new Foo {Id = 2, Name = "Foo"},
                    new Foo {Id = 3, Name = "Fooo"});

            modelBuilder.Entity<BarVW>(
                eb =>
                {
                    eb.HasKey(e => e.FooId);
                    eb.ToView("v_Bar");
                    eb.HasOne(e => e.Foo)
                        .WithOne(e => e.Bar)
                        .HasForeignKey<BarVW>(e => e.FooId);
                });
        }
    }
    
    public class FooDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsBar { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                @"CREATE VIEW [v_Bar] AS 
    select
        f.[Id] as [FooId],
        f.[Name] as [FooName]
    from
        [Foo] f
    where
        f.[Id] >= 1 and f.[Id] <= 2"
            );
            
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg => cfg
                    .CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
                        .ForMember(dto => dto.IsBar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Bar != null)));
            
            var result = context.Foo
                .ProjectTo<FooDto>(config)
                .ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(result.Count == 3);
            Debug.Assert(result.Count(dto => dto.IsBar) == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

The generated SQL for the query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT [f].[Id], CASE
    WHEN [v].[FooId] IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END AS [IsBar], [f].[Name]
FROM [Foo] AS [f]
LEFT JOIN [v_Bar] AS [v] ON [f].[Id] = [v].[FooId]
```

You can run the sample code using [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3yAEFd).